# Ruby 1.9: How to simplify this code that removes the leading and trailing p tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have strings that use simple_format so they always have p tags surrounding them. I have some code to strip those surrounding p tags but I know there has to be a better way. How would you simplify the following code?

```
<% my_string = "something" %>
<% my_string = simple_format my_string %>
```

Of course, `my_string` ends up with `<p>something</p>`

```
This removes the opening p tag. 
<% my_string[0..2] = "" %>

This removes the closing p tag.
<% my_string.chop! %>
<% my_string.chop! %>
<% my_string.chop! %>
<% my_string.chop! %>
```

Note: I don't want to remove ALL p tags, only the ones added by `simple_format`.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it should be done in the controller or a helper method. You're not supposed to be doing things like this in your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already applied the p tags:

```
mystring = "<p>something</p>"
# => "<p>something</p>"
mystring[3..-5]
# => "something"
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%- and -%>` suppress leading and trailing whitespace, including the trailing newline, and can be used interchangeably with `<% and %>`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html